# Recode in Python using the dictionary approach?

Tags: pandas

I'm pretty new to python and I'm trying to work out how to use the dictionary for recoding a variable into a new one.

I'm looking to recode the existing values of 1 and 2 into 1 and 3 and 4 into 2:

```
recode1 = {1 : 1, 2 : 1, 3 : 2, 4 : 2}
df['recode'].map(recode1)
```

It looks like all of the outputted variables are being given the NaN value.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including the definition of `df`, expected output, and actual output. You can [edit] the question. You're using Pandas, right? Please add the [tag:pandas] tag. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the warm welcome. The print command shows that I have the values of the dictionary correct:

    print(recode1)
    {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2}

I'd like to create a new variable on the dataframe using the values of an existing variable to recode/remap them into the values in the recode1 dataframe. Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score -1):

```
recode1 = {1 : 1, 2 : 1, 3 : 2, 4 : 2}
recode1[1]=recode1[1]
recode1[3]=recode1[2]
recode1[2]=recode1[4]
recode1
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2}
```

Comment: I am not much clear about your doubt but answered from what I understood

Comment: `recode` is the mapping of the values and you simply change it in some weird way (`recode1[1]=recode1[1]` makes no sense)... I believe the question is not very clear so I don't know how you could answer it. Secondly, your answer is also very unclear and code-only answers will much benefit from some explanations of how they actually solve the problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.